# How can I add custom HttpOperationHandlers to MVC 3 REST server?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

My back-end server is built using the Microsoft WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2. I want to add some request processing to all requests, except for those methods I explicitly disable by marking them with an attribute. I have over a hundred service methods and there are only a few I want to exclude from this extra processing. I'll tag them all if I have to, but I'm trying to avoid disrupting what's already written.

I haven't seen anything I can add to WebInvoke, and adding an interceptor won't let me examine the method that the request is routed to.

I am asking for an explanation of how to register HttpOperationHandler object(s) so I can do my extra request processing (i.e. authorization based on information in the request headers) before it is handed off to the method it was routed to. Can someone please explain how to do this, without rewriting my existing codebase to use Web API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adopting another method. It authenticates all requests. I can't control which method it applies to, but I was able to work around that.

I created a custom [ServiceAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.aspx) class to process the Authorization header. The `CheckAccess()` method returns true to allow the request through or false if the user is not authenticated or not authorized to perform the service. I hooked it up to the `ServiceHost` for my services by creating a custom [WebServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webservicehostfactory.aspx) class and assigning an instance to the `Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager` in its `CreateServiceHost()` methods.

Although I can't directly check method attributes for the service being executed, the `Message.Headers` member of the object passed to `CheckAccess()` has a `To` property that contains the URI of the service being called. If necessary, I could examine it to determine what method the request would be routed to.

The `ServiceAuthorizationManager` applies to all requests, so no web methods or classes must be marked with any special attributes to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an HttpOperationHandler with WCF REST Starter Kit.  However the Web API is very compatible with ServiceContracts that were created for WCF REST Starter kit.  You should be able to re-host them in a Web API host relatively easily.  You may have to change places where you access WebOperationContext, but it should not be a huge change.

Comment: Thanks, Darrel. I've seen many of your posts on the subject and appreciate your taking the time to help. As I didn't want to add another layer of unreleased libraries to my application, I decided to just authenticate all requests by using a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager, as explained below. +1 for the info.